# JDBC SQLite - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

Boa tarde,

Como eu faço para realizar a conexão com o BD do SQLite?
Fiz a classe de conexão assim.

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexao {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        // Variáveis
        Connection con  =   null;  
        String driver   =   "org.postgresql.Driver";
        String dir      =   "jdbc:sqlite:test.db";
        String user     =   "postgres_usuario";  
        String pass     =   "postgres_senha";    

        try {  
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");    
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dir, user, pass);    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }    
    }
}
```

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Não esta misturando dados de um banco `sqlite` com um `postgresql`? Poderia incluir também o erro gerado na sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim foi o que eu tentei fazer. Mais tudo o que muda não é só o Class.forName("Conteudo")?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer a conexão assim:

```
import java.sql.*;  

public class Test {  
    private Connection conexao;  
    public Statement statement;  
    public ResultSet resultset;  
    public PreparedStatement prep;  
  public void conecta() throws Exception {  
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
    conexao =  
      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");  
    statement = conexao.createStatement();  
   conexao.setAutoCommit(false);  
    conexao.setAutoCommit(true);  

  }  
  public void exec(String sql) throws Exception {  
   resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);  
  }  
public void desconecta()  
       {  
            boolean result = true;  
            try  
            {  
              conexao.close();  
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"banco fechado");  
            }  
            catch(SQLException fecha)  
            {  
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não foi possivel "+  
                      "fechar o banco de dados: "+fecha);  
              result = false;  
          }  

     }  
}
```

nesta linha ("jdbc:sqlite:test.db"); Onde esta "teste.db" é o nome de seu banco de dados.

ps: Sem esquecer de baixar o driver ODBC do sqlite ^^

Comment: Não posso votar porque o site diz que eu não tenho "15 pontos" de reputação.
Obrigado Dante!

Comment: Não se preocupe ^^ Marca a resposta como certa e quando tiver os 15 pontos volta aqui pra marcar como útil! De nada! :D